# In Vue 3, what is the correct type for a Vue component property?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Some of our components use other components as property.

A trivial example: `<my-interface-component :popup="myPopup"/>`
*Where myPopup will be a component with a `open` method that allows to open this external popup component with a message.*

In Vue 2 we used to set this property like this:

```
  /**
   * @prop {Vue} popup A root popup component to use
   */
  popup: {
    type: Vue
  },
```

And we could give either a component definition or an existing component reference.

But in Vue 3 there is no more such `Vue` object. Should I just use `Object` or is there a more explicit way?

We use the CDN version of Vue 3 with Vanilla JS.

Many thanks

Comment: is `myPopup` a component? if yes how do you want to render it inside the child component?

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim It is not necessarily rendered inside the child component, if it is a reference to an existing component it can just be used by this component. But if you pass a component definition and want to render it inside the child component you can (at least in Vue 2) just do `<component :is="popup"/>`

Comment: I thought that you're using typescript, you could do `<component :is="popup"/>` in vue 3

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim The `ComponentOptions` you suggested in not accessible in CDN version

Comment: Yes it won't work since typescript doesn't work there, try to type it as Object or String without using PropType utility

Answer (score 2):

The right type of a component is `ComponentOptions|ComponentOptions['setup']` which are simplified for readability as mentioned [here](https://vuejs.org/api/general.html#definecomponent):

```js
import {ComponentOptions, PropType } from 'vue'

props:{
  popup: {
    type: Object as PropType<ComponentOptions|ComponentOptions['setup']>
  },

}
```

However it's recommended to pass components/elements as slots not as props :

Child component :

```
<template>
  <div>
    <slot name="popup" />
  </div>
</template>
```

In parent :

```
<template>
 <div>
    <template #popup>
       <MyPopup />
    </template>
 </div>
</template>
```

Comment: Thanks. In my case the component I pass cannot be a child, it is actually a ref to another existing component - I will add this to my question. And also the fact I use Vanilla JS with the CDN version of Vue, and that the solution you suggested throws a syntax error.